# Why didn't the Mist obscure the water grabbing Nancy Bobofit?

Tags: percy-jackson

In the first chapter of *Percy Jackson and the Olympians: The Lighting Thief*, Percy unwittingly uses the water to grab Nancy Bobofit:

> I don't remember touching her, but the next thing I knew, Nancy was sitting on her butt in the fountain, screaming, "Percy pushed me!"
>   Mrs. Dodds materialized next to us.
>   Some of the kids were whispering: "Did you see —"
>   "—the water—"
>   "—like it grabbed her—"
>   I didn't know what they were talking about. All I knew was that I was in trouble again.
>   <sub>*Percy Jackson and the Olympians: The Lighting Thief*, chapter 1: "I Accidentally Vaporize My Pre-algebra Teacher"</sub>

Why didn't the Mist obscure the water grabbing Nancy Bobofit?

Answer (score -2):

I think that Rick Riordan purposely didn't let the Mist obscure the water because it wouldn't make sense. Nancy can't just teleport towards the fountain, right?

I also think that the water was shown because that way Percy could come closer to knowing he was a demi-god.

BTW - This is a theory

Comment: Are there any sources that led you to your conclusion?

Comment: @Edlothiad No, this is a theory.

Comment: Something must have led you to this theory?